# Product of Discrete Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, random-variables, convolution, products

I have a fair die 6-sided die labeled $1$ to $6$ on each side. Let $X_i$ be the face value of the $i^{th}$ roll. How would one go about finding the probability distribution for the product of the resultant rolls, i.e. for $PD=X_1\cdot X_2 \space$: $$PD=\prod_{i=1}^2X_i$$

I know $X_i$ will be independent and clearly brute force is a valid option here but what about when $n$ is large. I thought about the convolution of the probability generating function, but clearly we will have $P(PD=k)=0$ for some $k$. It would be nice if there was a equivalence of partitions and compositions for products of natural numbers.

Is there any theory I may have not seen that could find this product generally.

Comment: Do you know a little bit Integration theory and Fubini's theorem?

Comment: Ooohhh I don't but lets give it a go. Question isn't just for me, hopefully other users are interested! :)

Comment: $X_i$ is not an event, but a random variable. Further - on base of your definition of $PD$ - we will never have $PD=0$. What we do have is $P(PD=k)=0$ for lots of integers $k$. For instance $k=7$. A route you could go is looking at $\ln(PD)$ and practicize convolution.

Comment: As what drhab mentioned, using log will help you to turn the product into a sum which allow you to use the usual technique. However the exact solution when $n$ is large is deemed to be complicated and tedious, and can be done recursively with brute-force. When $n$ is really large, you may consider using CLT to get an approximate log-normal distribution.

Comment: I already have a tedious problem to deal with, no more please! Thanks for the comments guys! Will take a crack.